# How to enable user permission to dymaically mounted port in fedor 20

Tags: linux, cups

I have printer port which is use to mount in /dev/usb/lp0 port. But this port doesnot have user permission to access.How to give read & write permission to this file in fedora 20 when i every time plug in the cable ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: port does not have user permission to access?? What does this even mean?

Comment: i want to write a simple linux application, the printer which is mounted on the /dev/usb/lp0 port. The same application works in root mode.But being a normal user i cant able to print the data. I was able to achieve this in fedora 14 by writing rule file under /etc/rules.d. The same is not working in fedora 20.

Comment: this does not mean that port has permission or not. Infact, ports having permissions does not mean anything. There must be some printer config file, probably in /etc or /usr, you must change permission of that file. "PORT" has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: This can be can achieved using KERNEL=="lp0", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE="0666" command. This gives the permission to lp0 the moment printer is plugged on to the usb in fedora 14. But the same config is not working in fedora 20.

Comment: Ok then, I guess I'm not familiar with such conditions. Hope you get reqd help. :)